# Java GUI doesn't run smoothly

Tags: java, user-interface, button

I'm trying to write a Java GUI. I've been having problems where the program doesn't run smoothly; for example, the buttons take a very long time to appear and appear in wrong places. Below is my code and how the button looks like. Shouldn't the "start" be placed in a button? Is there a problem with my code because this has been happening for quite a while.

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class QuizGen {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Quiz Generator");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JButton start = new JButton("Start");
        start.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
        
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.add(start);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLgVc.png)

Comment: You shouldn't be using setBounds, your layout manager is handling that. Why do you add an empty panel to the frame?

Comment: Tysm for pointing out, I deleted the lines with the panel and the setBounds. However, my button is still not showing up.  Are there more problems with my code?

Comment: JFrames use BorderLayout by default and JPanels use FlowLayout by default. Add your button to the JPanel (without the setBounds), understand that layout managers usually respect preferred sizes much more than component sizes, don't forget to call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding all components and before setting it visible. Most of all, read the Swing tutorials. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: Also, can you include your updated code. If you just have a JFrame, and a JButton. If you add the JButton to the JFrame, it should be ok.